ValueError: shapes (64,100) and (10,100) not aligned: 100 (dim 1) != 10 (dim 0)
i got this error during implementation of training a 2-layer neural network
I try this code but it give the above error.
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randn
N, D_in, H, D_out = 64, 1000, 100, 10
x, y = randn(N, D_in), randn(N, D_out)
w1, w2 = randn(D_in, H), randn(D_out, H)

for t in range(2000):
    h = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x.dot(w1)))
    y_pred = h.dot(w2)
    loss = np.square(y_pred - y).sum()
    print(t, loss)

    grad_y_pred = 2.0 * (y_pred -y)
    grad_w2 = h.T.dot(grad_y_pred)
    grad_h = grad_y_pred.dot(w2.T)
    grad_w1 = x.T.dot(grad_h * h * (1 - h))

    w1 -= 1e-4 * grad_w1
    w2 -= 1e-4 * grad_w2

